# Is there a wavelength below which solid matter could not act as a clear refraction medium?

Tags: optics, solid-state-physics

Is there a theoretical limit for the wavelength of light that can pass through a solid? It appears that some borosilicate glasses can transmit UV light, but could any solid material act transparent to x-rays? or $\gamma$-rays?